# How to get all items from django-admin panel?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a html page where is

```
<body>
<h8>
    MY BLOGS
</h8>

<ul>
    {% for bl in all_blogs %}
        <li>{{bl.header}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In "ul" it must show all items from all_blogs what is

```
def list_blogs(request):
    all_blogs = Blog.objects.all
    return render(request, 'blogs.html', {'blogs': all_blogs})
```

and Blog is

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.header
```

and the output of the html page is just "MY BLOG" without any blogs in it, in my admin panel I have 4 blogs, I tried to print

```
for bl in all_blogs:
    print(str(bl))
```

but it doesnt work, I also checked local db for blogs, and it was fine.

Comment: `all` is a *method*, you should *call* it.

Comment: I did it, after in debug mode, it shows blogs properly inside all_blogs, but still nothing on html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`all()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#all) is a method, not a property, so you should *call* it to obtain the queryset of all `Blog` objects, so:

```
def list_blogs(request):
    all_blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blogs.html', {'blogs': all_blogs})
```

Furthermore in the context, you named the queryset `blogs`, *not* `all_blogs` (that is the name of the variable in the view, but you pass it as `'blogs'` to the context), hence you should either change the key in the view to `'all_blogs'`, or change the variable in the template to:

```
<ul>
    {% for bl in blogs %}
        <li>{{bl.header}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: While that's true, I don't think it can be OP's problem, as the method would be automatically called in the template, surely.

Comment: Thank for your answer, it helped. But I have a question, the name in the context is:
'blogs' in return render(request, 'blogs.html', {'blogs': all_blogs})?

Comment: Yes, it is the **`'blogs'`** part in `{'blogs': all_blogs }`, that is the idea of the dictionary, that you give values a "variable name" in the temlate. Since you could also use `{ 'three': 1 + 2 }`, but `1+2` is not a variable name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help